Integrate $ \int_{} \frac{\sin(x-a)}{\sin(x-b)} {\rm{d}}x$ smartly than rest?
Integrate $ \int_{} \frac{\sin(x-a)}{\sin(x-b)} {\rm{d}}x$

I am expecting better new elegant approaches for this simple integral and lets see the no. of other ways to solve it.

My try :
$$I = \int_{} \frac{\sin(x-a)}{\sin(x-b)} {\rm{d}}x = \int_{} \frac{\sin(x-b+b-a)}{\sin(x-b)} {\rm{d}}x = \int_{} \frac{\sin(x-a)\cos(b-a)+\sin(b-a)\cos(x-b)}{\sin(x-b)} {\rm{d}}x = x\cos(b-a) + \sin(b-a)\ln{|\sin(x-b)|} + C$$

$\sin(x-a)$ in the numerator of the first integral in the last line should probably be $\sin(x-b)$.

This is the shortest method I know as well. Something shorter than this is a general formula for this form of $f(x)$ I guess

@Gwen well my bad i didn't mean shortest one particularly but variety of other ways to solve it for example, using the Euler's formula of sinx or maybe feymann

Using Euler represntation of the sine function, the integrand is
$$e^{-i (a-b)}\,\, \frac{e^{2 i a}-e^{2 i x}}{e^{2 i b}-e^{2 i x}}$$
Let $x=-\frac{1}{2} i \log (t)$ to make
$$I=-\frac i 2\,e^{-i (a-b)}\,\,\int \frac{t-e^{2 i a}}{t \left(t-e^{2 i b}\right)}\,dt$$
Partial fraction decomposition
$$\int \frac{t-e^{2 i a}}{t \left(t-e^{2 i b}\right)}\,dt=\int \frac{e^{2 i (a-b)}}{t}\,dt+\int  \frac{1-e^{2 i (a-b)}}{t-e^{2 i b}} \,dt$$
Very simple integrals !

Why is this downvoted?

Claude passed the vibe check!!!

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad. I do not know this expression but now I learnt ! Thanks & cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici

@ClaudeLeibovici this is actually a Gen Z expression....so it is quite new

Put $x-b=u$ $\implies x-a=u+b-a$
$$I=\int \frac{\sin(u+b-a)}{\sin u} du$$
$$I=\int \frac{\sin u \cos(b-a)+\cos u\sin(b-a)}{\sin u}du$$
You must have realised that it is more or less same what you did. I just used another variable to type less. And I guess this is the shortest approach to these type of questions.

this is not the only way to integrate I mean using other ways it might or might not be shorter.

@Ash_Blanc they aren't shorter

let it not be shorter but a cooler approach not the one already in books n everywhere else

@Ash_Blanc you want a crazy approach??....apply complex analysis and solve it
